# How to add attachment of embed document in word file using apache poi in java

Tags: ms-word, apache-poi, embed, document

im trying to add embed excel file to table cell in a word document.But am not able to see any option using apache poi. Is their any otherways to do that in java?

Comment: did you get any idea on how to do this @sudheer reddy